# How do I update ViewController1 data with data passed back from ViewController2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have a navigationVC that loads a table view. When you tap a cell, it copies some data to a detailsVC, there's an update button to update the values. How do I refresh the data in the details VC without going back to the tableview and updating there first?

This is what I want to do:

> TableView>DetailsView>EditDetails> Back to DetailsView with updated info

Not this:

> TableView>DetailsView>EditDetails>DetailsView(via navigation back)> TableView>(pull to refresh)>DetailsView

EDIT

```
- (void) receiveNotifications:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"updateDetailsVC"]){
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
            NSLog (@"%@", userInfo);

            PRIORITYstring = [userInfo objectForKey:@"PRIORITY"];
        });
    }
}
```

i was able to get the code to work and via NSLog, my data is being pushed back as a dictionary.

when viewDidLoad for detailsVC, it runs a method that puts a NSString to its corresponding UILabel.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self displayData];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(receiveNotifications:)
                                           name:@"updateDetailsVC"
                                           object:nil];
}



-(void)displayData {
        PRIORITYlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Short Description: \n%@", QDESCRIPTIONstring];
}


- (void) receiveNotifications:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"updateDetailsVC"]){
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
            NSLog (@"%@", userInfo);

            PRIORITYstring = [userInfo objectForKey:@"PRIORITY"];
            //PRIORITYlabel.text = [userInfo objectForKey:@"PRIORITY"];
        });
    }
}
```

how would i go about getting the dictionary to override the initial data?

Comment: You can use block for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `NSNotificationCenter`. Post a notification from edit view, and subscribe for the same notification from table view and detail view.

**Posting notification::**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:nil userInfo: userInfo];
```

If you want to pass any data from edit view, you can make use of the `userInfo` dictionary!!

**Subscribing to the notification from table view and detail view ::**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
        name:@"TestNotification"
        object:nil];
```

**Action method ::**

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"TestNotification"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
        //retrieve the userInfo dictionary received from edit view
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
}
```

You can add this action method both in table view and detail view.

**Removing observer in table view and detail view ::**

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    // If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification Center
    // will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
    // object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

**EDIT ::**

You can update your displayData method to pass the label text as an argument.

```
-(void)displayData: (NSString*) labelText{
        PRIORITYlabel.text = labelText;
}
```

You can call the same from viewDidLoad and receiveNotifications: method.

**From viewDidLoad::**

```
[self displayData: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Short Description: \n%@", QDESCRIPTIONstring]];
```

**From receiveNotifications::**

```
[self displayData: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Short Description: \n%@", [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"PRIORITY"]]];
```

Comment: thanks for the code, ill check it out tomorrow. i was pulled to work on some other stuff so i haven't been able to test it.

Comment: so I'm able to get the data passed back via a NSDictionary. now my issue is to get that dictionary to replace a UILabel (or NSString thats tied to it) with the new data. I've updated my post to reflect

Comment: got it working as intended, thanks for all your help